# Implementing cache in streamlit using mysql.connector. Shows Type Error

Tags: mysql, caching, mysql-python, streamlit

#### The Code

First of all here's my code:

```
# importing mysql Connector .... nothing unusual
import mysql.connector as connection

# This function connects to an external database
def dbconn():
    try:
        return connection.connect(** st.secrets["mysql"])
        st.info("DB connected")
    except:
        return None
        st.info("DB NOT connected")
        
# This Variable stores the connection
DB_DATA = dbconn()

# Applying Cache
# The following function takes the DB_DATA variable in and does a lot of stuff with it
# For Example: Make Queries, printing to webpage, lots of pandas calculation
@st.cache(suppress_st_warning=True, hash_funcs={connection.network.MySQLTCPSocket: dbconn})
def my_func(mydb):
...<Code goes here>
```

> NOTE: `my_func` is meant to render a whole display page, not just to perform queries and calculations

#### The Error

Now that we have the code out of the way, here is the error I am getting:
[image: Type Error]

#### Here is the explaination:

My aim is to make **queries** inside `my_func()` while also **rendering outputs** and **graphs** to the screen. This function is meant to serve as a whole webpage(there are also other functions like this).
But as you might have guessed this process is extremely SLOW, therefore I want to apply `@st.cache` to it.

I have a feeling that I am doing something very stupid here since the error is a simple **Type Error**.

Any suggesstion on how do I fix it?
Also, did I provide sufficient info? I'll provide more if need be

Comment: i doubt your connect variable loks like this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html#

Comment: Oh no. Everything is working fine the way it is. I can connect to any DB with proper creds and make queries as well. The problem starts only when I add the `@st.cache` decorator

Comment: where did you find that construct @st.cache? have you any documentation for it?

Comment: If you want to discuss "SLOW", please provide the query that is slow, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: SLOW is not the problem I want to solve here ... I want to fix the `Type Error`